# Context of Main function in C or C++

Tags: c++, c

Does the main function we define in C or C++ run in a process or thread.
If it runs in a thread, which process is responsible for spawning it

Comment: "Process" and "Thread" are not in the Standard for either language, as far as I know.  The question is, strictly speaking, meaningless without some idea as to what platforms and implementations they are on.

Comment: I fear that you are suffering from a misconception that "process" and "thread" are fundamental concepts. These things are Standard Operating System Procedure (as it were) to the point that some languages (e.g. java) build them into the standard, but neither idea is necessary to a general purpose computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

main() is the entry point for your program.  C++ (current C++ anyway) doesn't know what a process or thread is.  The word 'process' is not even in the index of the standard.  What happens before and after main() is mostly implementation defined.  So, the answer to your question is also implementation defined.

In general though most operating systems have the concept of process and thread and they have similar meanings (though in Linux, for example, a thread is actually a "light weight process").  You can generally assume that your program will be started in a new process and that main() will then be called by the original thread after the implementation defined initialization.

Since there's plenty of room for the implementation and/or you to start up a whole bunch of threads before main is called though you will probably generally want to consider main() to have been called during the execution of a thread.  The best way to think about it though is probably in terms of the standard unless you really have to think about the implementation.  The standard doesn't currently know what a process or thread is.  C++0x will change that in some way but I'm not sure at this point what the new concepts will be or how they will relate to OS specific constructs.

My answer is specifically addressed at the C++ language part of the question.  C is a different language and I haven't used it in a good 10 years so I forget how the globals initialization is specified.

Comment: @Sirish: It is OS dependant.  Some OS's will spawn threads in their processes that do all the work.

Answer (score 3):

It's a process that you spawn when you execute your program.  The main function is called at the beginning of the program.  It is all a part of the same program (i.e. one process).

Comment: It is just one process, even if they call fork(), it spawns a new process.  No threads are spawned.  Depending on the OS though, it may treat the program as a thread within the process, but there is just one thread doing all the work of the program.  So, Michael is still right to a certain degree.

Comment: @Sirish:  The platform being run on may or may not have threads.  It probably has processes, or at least one process.

Comment: Hello @adhanlon could you tell me a document (universities' website, book, etc) where I can find the same informations you wrote in your answer please? I need it because I have to cite the references in my report.

Answer (score 2):

When you ask your OS to start a new process, it initializes data structures for a process and for a single thread inside that process.  The initial instruction pointer in that thread context is the process entry point, which is a function provided by your C runtime library.  That library-provided entry point converts the environment table and command-line arguments into the format demanded by the C standard, and then calls your main function.

Comment: None of which is actually necessary to c or c++, of course, this is just what modern, general-purpose OSs do. Either language can be defined to run in a bare-metal, unprotected environment that does not support processes or threads.

Comment: Bare-metal environments generally don't have a `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` function.  The question isn't "Context of power-on interrupt handler".

Comment: No need to get defensive, the comment was for the OP's benefit and you got my vote for a lucid summary. Certainly the embedded world is different, but there was a c compiler for the Apple II, and that ran programs in the same ring as the "OS": no protection was available. Likewise for early versions of DOS, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Your whole program is a single process unless it starts `fork()`ing things, and by default the process has one thread that does everything; `main()` starts on that thread